# Error in script component

Tags: c#, ssis

HI, i am geting following error while laoding the data from table1(stg) to table2(std).In the script component,I am trying to find  string "ABC" in perticular colulmn and replacing that string to "0.00" using c# in script component.

```
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.CheckStatusAndNull(Int32 columnIndex)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.GetDecimal(Int32 columnIndex)
at Input0Buffer.get_Underlying2()
at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer Buffer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

But the error displays here for some other column (Underlying2).Error says the column has null value.
I have applied the constraints as  cleanbuffer.column_isnull=true;
still it shows the same error.

please help to solve the above issue.I am new to c# coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this in a derived column?

ISNULL(std)==TRUE?NULL(DT_STR,10,1252):replace(std,"ABC","0.00")

The above line says
"If column std is null, then return a null, else return the string with ABC replaced by 0.00"

One thing to note.  In the example I assume the string is char(10)..replace the 10 with the appropriate size.